# Error while generating list from function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a function like this

```
def auto_correlation(dat, k):
   s = np.mean(dat)
   v = np.var(dat)
   N = dat.size
   sum = np.dot((dat[:N - k] - s), (dat[k:] - s))
   return 1 / v / (N - k) * sum
```

and want to create a list from it like this

```
autocorrOfTimeSeries = [auto_correlation(time_series,k) for k in range(50001)]
```

I always get the error

```
ValueError: shapes (4999,) and (0,) not aligned: 4999 (dim 0) != 0 (dim 0)
```

though. The Time series is just a 1 d array, and auto_correlation returns a single value.

Comment: For which value of `k` is it having this problem?  Start by testing the ends of the `range, 0 and 50000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably because at some point the slices `[:N-k]` and `[k:]` return different shapes.

One general issue is that to use vectorized (NumPy array-based) operations, you may need to pad your data series with 0s. You can also have a look at NumPy correlation functions https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html#numpy.correlate or SciPy's FFT-based correlation functions https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/signal.html#convolution-correlation